# What is the best way to forward (spoof) a production URL (port 80) on local rack development (port 5000)?

Tags: oauth, sinatra, foreman

I am new to heroku/sinatra and have an app with an oauth callback URL.  The simplest thing to do seems to be to modify `/etc/hosts` to spoof the production URL on my local machine, looping back to `127.0.0.1`

The problem is that when I use foreman or shotgun locally, they do not listen on port 80 (And I'd prefer for them not to)

What is the best way to make requests to my-app.herokuapp.com:80 be served by localhost:5000 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to achieve something like this as well, but wasn't able to direct request from one port to another without running a proxy (i.e. directing requests from port 80 in the browser to 5000 on the server).

However, I got this workaround that's fairly close:

```
# in your /etc/hosts file:
127.0.0.1  my-app.herokuapp.com
```

Then, if your Shotgun runs on port 5000, you should be able to acess `http://my-app.herokuapp.com:5000` in the browser.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. If I recall this was a Facebook apps question and another approach is simply to have multiple apps (e.g. staging and production) for this purpose